# How to "turn off" ADCS system to monitor orientation after firing MDT's?

Tags: cubesat, attitude-determination-and-control

I've been tasked in a hypothetical mission of determining if an Attitude Determination and Control System (ADACS) can be "turned off" during MEMS Digital Thruster (MDT) firings so that the spacecraft will move and calculate the moments that are generated from the firings. The mission involves a 3U CubeSat and the MDT's referenced above. I am going to use the reaction wheels and solve the "spin down" time that will release all the angular momentum of the vehicle and come to a stop before the MDT firings. I'm just wondering what next steps I'll need to look into to solve the problem at hand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "turn off" exactly? Typically, spacecraft have a subsystem for attitude control that is separate from the translational subsystem (i.e. the one that impars a delta v). In those systems, you can turn off ADCS before a maneuver and typically restore ADCS control immediately after the maneuver to cleanup any torques you may have created after the maneuver (due to imbalance).

Comment: The mission is to measure the translational and rotation motion of the cubesat after firing the MDT. I need the ADCS to not correct the cubesat after those firings. Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, that would be a requirement you'd place on the designers of the ADCS subsystem. That team would then need to implement a method to prevent the ADCS subsystem from cleaning up. The best person to task this with might be the systems engineer if you have one on your program.

Comment: Not to be glib, but you just throw a switch.  You tell your flight computer to stop issuing commands to the reaction wheels, and there is no more controlling.  If you need to have the wheels at 0 that is different, and I would ask why?

Comment: Thanks so much! I have first order calculations for spin down time of the reaction wheels. Maybe there’s research online for the switch and commands to the reaction wheels. I’ll need that for presentation purposes